# Cannot login to Sharepoint 2010 application from outside the server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I have installed a PNMSoft Sequence application on my server, which is based on Sharepoint 2010. Authentication for the application is configured with Claim authentication and Forms Based Authentication. I am able to login to the application from the server. However, when I am trying the login from a browser on a different server, I am getting an access denied error.[image]

I checked the ULS logs and i found an error:

`Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005 ffc01ea9-2988-453f-be1f-f1a79d34e28c`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you run the SharePoint config wizard after installing the PNMSoft Sequence application?

Comment: Sequence is dependent on SharePoint, so SharePoint needs to be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

You said "I am able to login to the application from the server. However, when I am trying the login from a different server."

What is the different server you are referring to? Another SharePoint server?

Can you ping the different server from the SharePoint server?

Check whether other users can access to the site from the issued server.

Comment: I meant a browser that exists outside of the server on which my application is installed. The application server is reachable on the network over port 8080 which my Sharepoint application is using.